His son died so he wants a revenge
I'm looking for a horror movie I watched a really long time ago so I don't really remember everything but this is what I do:
There's a creepy man who lost his son, I mean, his son died, so he wants a revenge. He invites all his son's friends at the party, in his home, and then he kills them, not all of them. And there is some kind of creepy little box. I don't know what's the thing about it but I think it's important to mention that. And it ends up when the man opens that box and some creepy people come from 'hell' (to call it like that) and they kill him.
So I watched it three years ago... 
It's american movie.
And sorry I don't remember anything else.. (:

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Hellraiser: Hellworld, the 8th Hellraiser movie from 2005.

The youngsters Chelsea, Allison, Derrick and Mike are grieving the suicide of their friend Adam, who became obsessed with an internet game called Hellworld. Their former friend Jake blames the group since they have not stopped playing the game even when Adam was unstable. When they receive an invitation to a Hellworld party in an isolated mansion, the reluctant Chelsea decides to join the group and they surprisingly find Jake in the party. He explains that he was invited by a girl he met in a chat room. They are hosted by the owner of the place, who shows them his private macabre collection. Along the night, they find that they are in a party in hell.

Some of the young friends are killed one by one and the party host then turns out to be Adam's father. The little box is a Lemarchand's box, which releases cenobites led by Pinhead. Here's the trailer:



